# PHP, javascript, cronjobs - Ajax test if user is online fail

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, random, cron

Good day to all. I have a strange problem.

I created a PHP script that inserts into a database the unix timestamp when it was accessed (PHP - time() function).

When a user is viewing a certain page a ajax request is send at every 57 seconds to the mentioned script.

I also created a cronjob that runs a PHP script that checks if the difference between the current time and the time logged in database for a certain user is higher than 2 minutes. The cron is set to run the script every 2 minutes, if is higher I mark the user as idle.

Now the problem is: Even though both seem to work fine, sometimes (seems very random to me) a user that is viewing the page is marked as idle. I can't find any explanation... perhaps any1 have an idea?

Unfortunately I can't provide an online version... but I answer any questions in max 10 mins.

The ajax script:

[image]

The insert script:

[image]

The cron:

[image: cronjob]

Thank you for help.

Comment: So what's your question. Why does the Ajax script fail? If it works normally, without seeing the script it's hard to say. Network failure?

Comment: I'm posting the script in 1 min.

Comment: Please post real code and not pictures of code. Potential repliers won't enjoying retyping.

Answer (score -1):

Does your user hava Javascript enabled? Is your server getting the AJAX requests from that specific user?

Comment: I'm the user... i'm testing :) so yes